# How to display words found in a string using C#?

Tags: c#, regex

While I am able to replace words using regex and here is my code:

```
public static string replacestring(string input)
{
   var Words = "memory|buffer overflow|address space|stack overflow|call stack";
   string cleanword = Regex.Replace(input, @"" + Words + "", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
   return cleanword;
}
```

And here is the string value:

> In software, a stack overflow occurs if the call stack pointer exceeds the stack bound. The call stack may consist of a limited amount of address space, often determined at the start of the program. The size of the call stack depends on many factors, including the programming language, machine architecture, multi-threading, and amount of available memory. When a program attempts to use more space than is available on the call stack (that is, when it attempts to access memory beyond the call stack's bounds, which is essentially a buffer overflow), the stack is said to overflow, typically resulting in a program crash.

How do I pick up and display those words found in a string and count them?

For example

> Found: stack overflow,address space,call stack,memory,buffer overflow
>   Count:5

A million thanks in advance an greatly appreciated and sorry for any inconvenience caused.

Answer (score 3):

You could start with something like this:

```
string wordsToMatch = "memory|buffer overflow|address space|stack overflow|call stack";
string input = "In software, a stack overflow occurs if the call stack pointer exceeds the stack bound. The call stack may consist of a limited amount of address space, often determined at the start of the program. The size of the call stack depends on many factors, including the programming language, machine architecture, multi-threading, and amount of available memory. When a program attempts to use more space than is available on the call stack (that is, when it attempts to access memory beyond the call stack's bounds, which is essentially a buffer overflow), the stack is said to overflow, typically resulting in a program crash.";

var wordsFound = new List<string>();
foreach (string word in wordsToMatch.Split('|')) {
    foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, word, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)) {
       if (match.Value.Equals(word)) {
           wordsFound.Add(match.Value);
       }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Found: " + string.Join(",", wordsFound.Distinct()));
Console.WriteLine("Count: " + wordsFound.Distinct().Count());
```

Output:

> Found: memory,buffer overflow,address space,stack overflow,call stack
>
> Count: 5

http://rextester.com/CYRL45262

Comment: Word boundaries might be a good thing, to prevent partial word. anyway just a note

Comment: @MichaelRandall I would agree, but I'm only answering what OP has asked.

Comment: You find all occurences of the word case insensitively. Then you remove occurences that do not match case. And finally remove all occurences except one. I have to say the code intentions are really puzzling. Why don't you just find the first occurence case sensitively?

Comment: @AntonínLejsek Okay.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to remove duplicates and return the count number of the array.

```
var count = Regex.Matches(str, pattern).OfType<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[0].Value).Distinct().ToArray().Count();
```

Output:

```
5
```

[Code demo](https://ideone.com/SLZqVN)

Answer (score 0):

You can use split function of the string like this:

```
var result = Words.split(new char[] {'|', ' '}) ;
var wordCount = result.Length;
```

Comment: I think adding some more detail/explanation would greatly improve your answer.

Comment: I guess I didn't understand the question at first

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using linq as an alternative: 
This also addresses the implied uniqueness in the OP.

```
var toMatch = "memory|buffer overflow|address space|stack overflow|call stack";
Regex reg = new Regex(toMatch, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var result = reg.Matches(input)
                .OfType<Match>()
                .Where  (m => m.Success)
                .GroupBy(m => m.Value)
                .Select (m => new { Word = m.First().Value, QtyFound = m.Count() });

var wordsFound = string.Join(",", result.Select(r => r.Word));
var totalFound = result.Sum(r => r.QtyFound);
```